# How to add Silverlight controls to a WPF Solution?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, reference, controls

I'm kinda new to WPF and .Net programming in general.
I have downloaded this [Source Code](http://rajneeshnoonia.com/blog/uploads/code/BookDemo.zip).

Now, it has a solution which contains a Paris.Controls csproj.

This was originaly made for Silverlight, when i try to add referance to the outputed dll of those controls, i get an error:

```
               Error    1   Unknown build error, 
'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly
         'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
     PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' 
        because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies
         must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event. 
        Line 9 Position 80.'    C:\Users\Eric\Documents\Visual Studio 
        2010\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml   9   80
            WpfApplication1
```

After a bit of googling, i found out It's most likley because of the Silverlight - WPF transformation.
That Silverlight uses different referances then WPF.
Which is kinda dumb i think because as i understood Silverlight is a substraction of WPF, but nevermind.

So my question is what should i do and how?
Should i edit the Paris.Controls and make it WPF-Available?
Change referances and stuff like that? and if that's what i should do,
How do i do that?
And if not, what are my options?

Please help guys,
Sincerly yours,
Eric

Comment: SilverLight and WPF UI controls were not interchangeable and Microsoft is very clear on that.   Look for a WPF control that does what you need.  If you are new to WPF and .NET then converting a control is not a good first project.

Comment: Problem is, there isn't a good one =/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

Silverlight and WPF, while very similar are based on different versions of the .NET runtime. WPF uses the full version, while Silverlight uses a lighterweight version optimised for the Internet.

As you have the source code you should be able to incorporate that into a WPF control - it will mean recompiling against the full libraries and fixing any errors that the compiler throws up.

Comment: But the error isn't pointing out where in code i can change the referance. Got a clue?

Comment: @eric.itzhak - are you just trying to reference the Silverlight control as already built or are you trying to recompile the source?

Comment: I'm not sure i understood the question. I want to be able to use that control in a WPF. as the controls are referancing silverlight, isn't my only option to recompile the source to create a dll? i don't know of any other way to referance to controls. asked that as well at the question above.

Comment: @eric.itzhak - yes you have to recompile the source against the WPF libraries. There will be differences.

Comment: Ya trying to that for the past hour. seems to be too many changes and not enough information on web. System.Windows should be changed to what? and where can i find TemplateVisualState in WPF?

Comment: @eric.itzhak - Issues like that would be worth their own question. Though it would probably be easier to take BalamBalam's advice and look for a native WPF control.

Comment: belived me i tried that before. But thank you for all your help!