# Recompile Silverlight to WPF issues

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, compiler-errors

I have a Silverlight control i need to convert to WPF
(Yes, i know that's not wise, don't have a choice)
And i am aware that some assemblies need to be changed.
this is a follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318701/how-to-add-silverlight-controls-to-a-wpf-solution)

Now i am kinda sure that i'm missing a big thing here.
DIdn't really know how to do that so i just started copying all the cs files code to new 
class project.
Now i get all kind of weirds errors.
Most for assemblies missing ( ofcourse),
Now what i fail to understand is i'm missing very basic stuff and i am calling the right ones i belive. stuff i used in other WPF applications.
for isntance i get Errors for theese classes :
**Point, Size, UIElement, DependencyProperty, MouseEventHandler etc.**

*Now the project is just 14 classes, no main file or anything, could this be related?*

Anyway, i'm using this code to call assemblies (preety much the same anywhere):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
```

And the VS isn't givining me on help any assembly i could call, just the option to generate my own class.

I am targeting Framework 4.0 using VS 2010

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you put this control in a new WPF project? If you didnt make sure you add these References

- PresentationFramework
- PresentationCore
- WindowsBase
- System.Xaml

Then remove all your using Statements and readd them all.

You also may need

- System.Drawing depending on what Point you are using

Comment: This made all the errors go away, and understood my initial mistake. thank you!

Comment: Ya still waiting for the time to pass, btw my bad i still have 14 warnings and 1 error, the RootVisual class is missing - any idea where might i find it?

Comment: RootVisual = Application.Current.MainWindow

Comment: No that didn't work. tried Application.Current.RootVisual; and yours... no good :o should i try the getRootVisual()? is it the same?

Comment: I changed : "return Application.Current.RootVisual;" To : "return Application.Current.MainWindow.GetRootVisual();" , I'm good to go?

Answer (score 2):

[`UIElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx) is in `System.Windows` and you'll need to make sure that `PresentationCore.dll` is referenced by your project.

[`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx) is in the same namespace but required `WindowsBase.dll` to be referenced.

[`MouseEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventhandler.aspx) in `System.Windows.Input` which is also in `PresentationCore`.

It might be simpler to create an empty WPF project which should have the basic references set up and then adding the source to that.

Comment: will i be able to save it as dll in the end?

Comment: @eric.itzhak - yes. See MyKuLLSKI's answer for the basic ones your need.

Comment: Ya that solved it, thank you for helping me realise im an idiot :)

Comment: @eric.itzhak - nope you're not an idiot. You've been given a difficult task and are approaching it in a methodical way and trying to resolve the problems it throws at you. Hopefully Stack Overflow has given you the background as well as the immediate solutions.